# Mapeamento de aplicações Web

Tags: banco-de-dados, servidor, servidor-de-aplicação, mapas

Olá, 
Gostaria de saber se conhecem alguma ferramenta Open-Source para fazer o mapeamento das aplicações Web, não sei qual é o nome para esse tipo de aplicação.
Basicamente o que quero saber das aplicações é: 
1 - Quais são os servidores web que a app está rodando
2 - Quais servidores de banco de dados que estão sendo usandos por essa app
...

Obrigado

Comment: Você quer uma forma de expor essas informações ou está questionando quais ferramentas deveria usar?

Comment: Oi @GiulianaBezerra, na vdd queria uma ferramenta para organizar e mostrar essas informações de uma forma fácil.
Eu posso criar uma planilha excel e fazer esse "De" "Para" mas acredito que deva existir ferramentas de mercado feitas para isso